# Allow several users on the same IP to connect

Tags: mumble

I am hosting a murmur server that I use with my friends, and everything has worked well up until this point. My brother came over and we wanted to play some co-op games, so I downloaded mumble on his machine but couldn't connect to the server. It doesn't appear in the list as a LAN server, but if I add the IP manually (both the local and public IP) it shows up in the list, BUT he still cannot connect. The log just keeps saying "<2:(-1)> Connection closed: The remote host closed the connection [1]". I've tried changing settings such as the bonjour announcement in the murmur.ini, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have complete control over the mumble server itself?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it's hosted on a machine in my local network